# Define interface by an array of values

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have a constant with input props and a function that returns the input ids and its default value, like this:

```
const Inputs = [{label: "myInput1", id: "myId1"}, {label: "myInput2" , id: "myId2" }]
    
const getInputValues = () => Inputs.reduce( (acc, item) => ({...acc, [item.id] : 123  }), {} )
```

How can I define the return type of `getInputValues` in TypeScript?

[Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAkmADgVyhGBeGBtA3gGwEMAjAU3wC4YAiAWwE8EUoBGagGhgEsATKuxjzYBfTgRLl%20DJqgBM1GJ15TB8mMIC6AWABQMfTF2hIsAOakoMqADVC%20ZKXRYAFAEpMAPnhJUEAHQATqQ8yMCkzjDOhMDASlCktO4YXs64funRsThc8bR%20vBowVCyyAMz6wq5iwjCuQA)

Comment: I don't want to use any. There is no way to do it without any?

Comment: Did you tried making an interface as your question title displays ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could think of is to use const assertion for your `Inputs` constant:

```js
const Inputs = [
  {label: "myInput1", id: "myId1"},
  {label: "myInput2", id: "myId2"},
] as const;

type InputIds = typeof Inputs[number]['id'];

function getInputValues(): Record<InputIds, number> {
  return Inputs.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return {...acc, [item.id]: 123};
  }, {} as Partial<Record<InputIds, number>>) as Record<InputIds, number>;
}
```

Comment: `{[K in InputIds]: number}` can be replaced with `Record<InputIds, number>`,

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank you! Definitely more readable. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can hope for here is [`Record<string, number>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

```
const getInputValues = ():Record<string,number> => 
    Inputs.reduce( (acc, item) => ({...acc, [item.id] : 123  }), {})
```

For even better type-safety, you might choose `Record<string, number | undefined>` which will force you to type-check any values you access.